# How to display images whose locations are in a JSON file accessed through XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: html, json, xmlhttprequest

Here is a sample of the JSON data (https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images):

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2018-12-19T15:18:38+08:00",
      "cameras": [
        {
          "timestamp":"2018-12-19T15:17:18+08:00",
          "image":"https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2018/12/d18c7fee-f2a4-454a-b68f-c21dd3c34493.jpg",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 1.29531332,
            "longitude":103.871146
          },
          "camera_id": "1001",
          "image_metadata": {
            "height": 240,
            "width": 320,
            "md5": "230ef16904c20b3108d7b5c378912a4a"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "2018-12-19T15:17:18+08:00",
          "image": "https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2018/12/2cca04f5-7c76-4887-a683-85f5f2f7e5fa.jpg",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 1.319541067, 
            "longitude": 103.8785627
          },
          "camera_id": "1002",
          "image_metadata": {
            "height": 240,
            "width": 320,
            "md5": "818f64f1362871f28780ee6721c0befa"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My html code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  function loadDoc() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images",true); 
    // ...
    xhr.send();
  }
</script>
```

I am still very new to html and ajax in general so correct me if I am wrong,
but is timestamp in the array of items? Also is it better to extract the image from the `xhr.responseText` directly? Is there a way to do it?

Basically the image link will keep changing every 20 seconds as it is displaying live feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Each item has a timestamp
2. Use `'json'` as response type in the XHR, then you have the data in xhr.response:

   ```
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
   xhr.open('GET','https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images',true)
   xhr.responseType = 'json'
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return
     const data = xhr.response
     const element = document.getElementById('demo')
     element.innerHTML = ''
     for (let item of data.items) {
       for (let camera of item.cameras) {
         const img = document.createElement('img')
         img.src = camera.image
         element.appendChild(img)
       }
     }
   }
   xhr.send(null)
   ```

Comment: Hi Nathan, Correct me if I'm wrong,
so you assign XMLHttpRequest to constant variable named data.

Loop let item of data.items meaning this statement is looking for the elements of items in data.items?

and the nested loop looks for camera in items.cameras?

I don't really understand how you deduce that by looking at each item having a timestamp! Do you mind if I i can contact you via PMs to get more answers?

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>  <p id = "demo"></p>  <script> function loadDoc(){  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const data = xhr.response;
      for (let item in data.items) {
        for (let camera of item.cameras) {
          const imageUrl = camera.image;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = imageUrl;
  }
 }
xhr.open("GET","https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images",true);
xhr.send(); 
};</script>
I wrote this but when i click the button no images appear! I tried to formatt the code but it doesnt work...